# Change textLabel.text without reloading the view?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, label, uilabel

i have a game, which update method is called every 0.5 seconds. and i have a second method which is called every 2 seconds and should change the text in my Labels:

```
func changeName(){
    textLabel.text = "this is a test, 4 U <3"
    textLabel.hidden = false
}
```

but then all my other views (in VC) are reseting to their original position. i don't know why!
Can anyone please help me??
i tried it with UIViews and it  worked perfect, with hiding. But there seems to be a prob with the name changing. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If what you are saying that the width of your UILabel changes with the text, then I suggest you add constraint on the UILabel's width. If you are using storyboard select the UILabel in the SB and click the lower right icon like in this picture and check width:

[image]

Comment: no, i don't change the with. Just the text... and that its hidden

Comment: Yes but if the UILabel's width isn't constrained, then it will default to its intrinsic size, meaning it will wrap around the content in this case. See my updated answer.

Comment: i have all my contains and the labels aren't moving or anything.. but you may got a point with that, wait a sec.

Comment: I added a picture so you can see how to go about it.

Comment: see it but it didn't work. i also want to make it for every device, so my constrains are for each to the left and to the right

Comment: This is about constraining in a smart way -- if you have things to the left and the right, then simply set a maximum spacing in relation to the label; like that the label will never grow above a certain width. You can also play around with priorities. Unless you give more information about the views and the desired behaviour, there's not much else I can do :)

Comment: alright. but still the views are all reloading to their position after i set a new text... anyway, thanks a lot, my friend :)

Comment: Ah, are you animating the views by any chance?

Comment: no, not really. Just changing the text in a timer func every .2 seconds. But my views always reset to the position i set in the storyboard. Is there a possible way to change the text without resetting all other views? like above i set my with constrain, so the label isn't changing its constrains. any more help?